# Passing array values to Nvd3 chart

Tags: arrays, nvd3.js

This is my array.

```
var array = [{"month":"January","url":1,"ip":12},
{"month":"February","url":102,"ip":200},{"month":"March","url":192},
{"month":"June","ip":10}];
```

Is there any possible way to pass these array as x axis and y axis values in line chart?.

I have tried like this.

```
function() {
 var array = [{"month":"January","md5":1,"ip":12},
{"month":"February","url":102,"ip":200},{"month":"March","url":192},
{"month":"June","ip":10}];
var data=[], data2=[];


<div id="chart">
<svg></svg>
</div>


 for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
data.push({x: array[i].url, y: array[i].month})
   data2.push({x: array[i].ip, y: array[i].month});
}

 return [
{
  values: data,
  key: 'URL',
  color: '#ff7f0e'
},
 {
  values: data2,
  key: 'IP',
  color: '#ff7f0e'
}
 ];
}


nv.addGraph(function() {
  var chart = nv.models.lineChart()
 .useInteractiveGuideline(true)
 ;

   chart.xAxis
  .axisLabel('Time (ms)')
  .tickFormat(d3.format(',r'))
 ;

 chart.yAxis
  .axisLabel('Voltage (v)')
  .tickFormat(d3.format('.02f'))
  ;

 d3.select('#chart svg')
 .datum(data())
  .transition().duration(500)
  .call(chart)
  ;

 nv.utils.windowResize(chart.update);

 return chart;
});
```

I am not able to pass x axis values from array. is there any possiblw way to pass these array into line chart of nvd3?

Comment: Include a JSFiddle next time.

Answer (score 0):

For future questions, please always include a JSFiddle link. The code you provided was not valid Javascript and it makes more work for other people to answer.

I think this is what you are trying to achieve: http://jsfiddle.net/992gdb83/1/

Things you need to do:

a. You're using an ordinal scale (months), therefore follow the approach from here: https://github.com/novus/nvd3/issues/29

```
  var months = ["January", "February", "March", "April"];

  chart.xAxis.axisLabel("Time (ms)").tickFormat(function(index) {
    return months[index];
  });

  chart.x(function(d, i) {
    return i;
  });
```

b. You're missing data for URL/IP at certain time points.

c. You should probably use the .x/.y accessor functions

d. Your code is formatted poorly. Use https://prettier.io/playground/

Comment: i want to select months from var array = [{"month":"January","md5":1,"ip":12},
{"month":"February","url":102,"ip":200},{"month":"March","url":192},
{"month":"June","ip":10}]; instead of defining once again in var months = ["January", "February", "March", "April"];

Comment: Well use basic JS for that. const months = array.map((data) => data.month);